# Run an external script using [!][1] having a dynamic input variable

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to run an external in matlab script using [exclamtion mark (!)](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html;jsessionid=5f3a49bec5f22beb05f41b1c3620) having as an input a variable from workspace?

Example:
`input_var` is a variable in my workspace

```
!python scriptname input_var
```

Thank you!

Comment: See [system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html)

Comment: I think both `system` and `!` just go and call command line scripts, so I'd say nope

Comment: If input_var is a simple type, then yes. By simple I mean a number or a string, or other data types that can be forwarded to python as a string